# Normal spaces in box and uniform topology

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb{R^\omega}$ normal in product topology? In the uniform topology? and In box topology?

My attempt:I know it is normal in uniform topology because it is metrizable. I would gues that it is normal in product topology. But do not know how to go about proving it.

Comment: Are you asking about the ordinary product topology, or about the box product topology?

Comment: Oh yes, good point. The title says box, but the post says product.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It was my mistake. I meant all three topologies. Sorry about that. I have modified my question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a standard theorem that the ordinary product of at most countably many metric spaces is metrizable, so $\Bbb R^\omega$ is normal in both the uniform and the usual product topologies. The continuum hypothesis implies that it is paracompact and therefore normal in the box topology; I’m not sure whether there are known models of set theory in which it is definitely not normal in the box topology.